# Why is there a strange "thinning" effect visible on these span tags after the transition has finished?

Tags: css

Despite using [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) when I try to make this navigation icon, [originally from Jesse Couch](https://codepen.io/designcouch/pen/Atyop), thinner, then after the transition the span tags seems to get a second effect applied to them, making them a tiny tad more thinner. Why is this happening? Sorry I cannot really word this better but [please see for yourself](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lmowgk3/). Firefox version 28 up to 50 shows this effect, Chrome latest version however does not and not tested this in Opera or IE11/Edge.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}

/* normalize.css included */

#nav-icon {
  width: 60px;
  height: 45px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* When I change the default value of 9px to something lower there is a strange "thinning" effect visible on the span tag after about half a second, why?*/
#nav-icon span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px; /* 9px is the default value, lowering this has a strange after effect on the span tags, why? */
  width: 100%;
  background: #d3531a;
  border-radius: 5px; /* 9px is the default value, lowering this has a strange after effect on the span tags, why? */
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}


#nav-icon span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(2),#nav-icon span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 18px;
}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 36px;
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Looks like Firefox uses a different drawing routine during transition than after the end.

Comment: https://github.com/integrations seems to also suffer from this on Firefox.